# (BASIC) I get nothing when using open('example.txt', 'r')

Tags: python, append

Here is my doubt, i wrote a code so if a line in a .txt starts with a certain word, it appends the whole line starting from where it finds a space. That is ***"test2"***, and it worked well untill i wrote another piece of code ***(test)*** between the lines that declarates the open and reading of the *.txt*, and the code that appends the line if it contains certain word. In other words, ***test2*** won't append anything unless i delete the ***'test'*** part of the code that is located in the middle. Why is that?. Is because 'test' is already with the file open so 'test2' can't read it? it's a conflict?.

```
import csv

appending = open('Hi.txt', 'a')
reading = open('Hi.txt', 'r')
writer = csv.writer(appending)

for test in reading:
    if test.startswith('blabla'):
        print(test)


for test2 in reading:
    if test2.startswith('blabla'):
        word = test2.find(' ')
        word = test2[word :]

        writer.writerows([word])
```

Comment: The first `for test in reading:` uses up the generator returned by `open('Hi.txt', 'r')` thus when you reach the second `for test2 in reading:`, there'd be nothing left to read hence there'd be nothing to append.

Comment: You can do `reading.seek(0)` before `for test2 in reading:`.

Comment: You do know that you're opening the same file, right? Or is the first `'Hi.txt'` a typo?